# webpack generating unnecessary output file

Tags: webpack, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm using multiple entry points (one to generate the bundled js file (main.js) and the other to generate the css file (style.css). My webpack.config.js file is generating both of those files but also a style.js file. How do I make it not generate the style.js file?

webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  entry: {
    main: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      path.join(__dirname, './app/main.js')],

    style: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      path.join(__dirname, './app/main.css')]},

  // any way to indicate that only the 1st entry point should be output to a file?
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.tpl.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        "presets": ["react", ["es2015", { "modules": false }], "stage-0", "react-hmre"]
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.json?$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })
    }]
  }
};
```

The ExtractTextPlugin uses the style entry point to generate the css file, I don't want that entry point used in the bundle output. Is there any way to only have the main (1st) entry point used for the output? Or should I change my approach to generate the style.css file completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick fix**: remove the second `.css` entry. You only need the `.js` entry.

```
entry: {
    main: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      path.join(__dirname, './app/main.js')
    ],

    // Remove this entry!
    // style: [
    //   'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    //   path.join(__dirname, './app/main.css')
    // ]
}
```

You need to **import** or **require** all the used `.css` files (your `main.css`) somewhere in at least one of your `.js` files like this (I use typescript):

`import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";`

---

**Why?**

> The ExtractTextPlugin uses the style entry point to generate the css
>   file ...

***No, it doesn't!***

The way `Webpack` works is that:

1. it generates the dependency graph by looking at the `import` and
   `require` sections in all of your `javascript` files starting from
   provided entries.

   [image]
2. With each file in the dependency graph `Webpack` applies loaders
   base on the the `test` property of all loader objects. This is where
   the `ExtractTextPlugin` **loader** comes in. It will take care of
   all the `.css` files in the graph.
3. Finally, it applies all the specified plugins. Again, the
   `ExtractTextPlugin` **plugin** will come in to finish the work that
   `ExtractTextPlugin` **loader** has started.